# How do I use the Characters Object in Excel VBA with a variable rather than a cell reference

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to return each character in a string.
*I know that the same can be accomplished by making use of MID but, this is just a small part of a bigger script for which I need to determine the characters in italic.*

The following works correct:

```
For x = 1 To Len(Activecell)           
    MsgBox Activecell.Characters(x, 1).Text
Next x
```

However trying to do the same with a variable in which the string is stored does not work:

```
V = "blabla blabla blabla"
For x = 1 To Len(V)           
    MsgBox V.Characters(x, 1).Text
Next x
```

Is there a way to use the Characters object in combination with a variable in which the string is stored?

Comment: If you want to use the `Characters` property of a `Range` object then you need to get the string into a `Range` object. Any chance you can just populate a range on a hidden sheet?

Comment: That's unfortunately not possible in my case. :(

Comment: Is the string you're putting into a variable coming from a cell? and if so, why can't you just reference the cell directly?

Comment: What if you declare `V As Range` and then `Set V = ActiveCell` or whatever cell you need to?

Comment: Characters in a `String` variable don't have formatting, so what is the actual point?

Comment: The thing is that I need to store the string in a variable and than replace some characters before I can work with it. However I do not want to replace these characters in the cell

Comment: @Rory, I see your point. Thank you for pointing that out! Now it makes sense. I was doing it all wrong. Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to find the characters to replace on the cell itself if you're looking for italic etc., then replace them in a string variable.

Answer (score 2):

So it seems you don't want to change your values in a cell, but rather in a variable. However, font information is stored in a cell containing a value. And since `Characters` is a `Range` property, it won't work on a variable. You'd need to iterate the characters in the actual cell and change your variable accordingly. For example, let's say this is cell `A1`:

[image]

```
Sub Test()

Dim V As String: V = [A1]

For x = 1 To Len(V)
    If Range("A1").Characters(x, 1).Font.Italic Then
        V = Application.Replace(V, x, 1, "k")
    End If
Next x

Debug.Print V

End Sub
```

Returns:

```
blakla blakla klabla
```